# Beamer , conference poster change the header area

Tags: beamer, templates

I am making a conference poster using a template provided in this link.
http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/latex-poster-template/

I want to reduce the size of the header area ( Title area), may be by reducing the font size and spacing.
How can I change those parameters?

Comment: if you look in `beamerthemeconfposter.sty` (provided in the `.zip` file in your link) you should be able to tweak lines `182-201` to suit your needs

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

As [@cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) pointed out in his comment, you can tweak the `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`. Just include the following lines somewhere after `\usetheme{confposter}`. The lines you might first want to try changing them are marked with `% CHANGE this line ...`

```
%==============================================================================
% build the poster title
%==============================================================================
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}
        \Huge % CHANGE this line for the size of the title
        {\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}
        \Large % CHANGE this line for the size of the author
        {\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}
        \large % CHANGE this line for the size of the institut
        {\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in} % CHANGE this line for the space between your title and the horizontal rule
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in} % CHANGE this line for the space between your horizontal rule and your main body
}
```